# how to stop a discord bot from reacting to a command once it has been used?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
if command_done == True:
@client.listen("on_message")
async def on_message(sent):
    if sent.channel.id == (1043523838580895857):
        messagesent = sent.content
        if messagesent == "!start":
            return
        print(messagesent) 

@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    channel = client.get_channel(1043523838580895857)
    timewait = random.randint(300,600)
    await channel.send("working!")
    command_done = True
    if command_done == True:
        print("true")   
    last_sent = await 
    channel.fetch_message(channel.last_message_id)print(last_sent.content)
```

im trying to make a command on my discord bot that will have a command like "!start". once this command has been used and a user tries to say "!start" again, nothing will happen. it would work like a toggle on and off, where once the command is on it cannot be turned on again, it can only be turned off. is there anyway i can do this?

i have tried to use @client.listen to listen for when a user types the command, and then it'll return nothing, but this didn't work.

Comment: Show us your relevant code!

Comment: In your !start handler, set a global flag to True.  Then, at the start of the handler, if the flag is already True, just return.

Comment: @KlausD. sorry! have added the code now

Comment: You have to put the `if` in the handler function, not above it.

Comment: @TimRoberts please could you explain just a little bit more? i dont quite understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code, modified so it should work.

```
command_done = False

@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    global command_done
    if command_done:
        return   
    command_done = True
    channel = client.get_channel(1043523838580895857)
    await channel.send("working!")
    last_sent = await channel.fetch_message(channel.last_message_id)
    print(last_sent.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly but the following would work as toggle switch. Meaning on the first execution of !start, the bot will send a message, on the second execution it will do nothing and on third execution it will send the message again and so on ...

```
startflag = 0
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def start(ctx):
    global startflag
    if startflag == 0:
        startflag = 1  # toggle it on
        await ctx.send("we started")  
    else:
        startflag = 0 # toggle it off again
```